# Dalitz plot for $ \pi \to \gamma (1) + e^+ (2) + e^- (3) $

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am studying the decay above and I need an exact form of Dalitz plot in coordinates $m^2_{12}, m^2_{23}$ to integrate over three-particle phase-volume. Please, tell where to read about it?

I tried to compute it by myself but I stuck on calculations.

Comment: You are missing a 0  after the pi .AFAIK a Dalitz plot is used to plot data. http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/staff/academic/gershon/talks/gershon-BadHonnef.pdf  If you have the decay matrix element you could put it  in a monte carlo generator to give points in the dalitz plot.